# How do header and source files in C work?

Tags: c, compilation, header-files

I've perused the possible duplicates, however none of the answers there are sinking in.

**tl;dr: How are source and header files related in `C`? Do projects sort out declaration/definition dependencies implicitly at build time?**

I'm trying to understand how the compiler *understands* the relationship between `.c` and `.h` files.

Given these files:

**header.h**:

```
int returnSeven(void);
```

**source.c**:

```
int returnSeven(void){
    return 7;
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"
int main(void){
    printf("%d", returnSeven());
    return 0;
}
```

Will this mess compile? I'm currently doing my work in **NetBeans 7.0** with **gcc** from Cygwin which automates much of the build task. When a project is compiled will the project files involved sort out this implicit inclusion of `source.c` based on the declarations in `header.h`?

Comment: Yes, this will compile (and why do you think it's a "mess"?). The concepts to learn about are **compilation units** and **linkage**.

Comment: Thanks **Jesper**; Haha, it's not a mess, I suppose that word is best reserved for describing my brain, reading between 3 beginner level `C` books. I'll certainly look into *compilation units* and *linkage*, however for the sake of focusing on learning syntax, I'll let **NetBeans** + **gcc** figure this out for me. Given that, whenever a given header file has declarations for which definitions exist elsewhere in the project, the inclusion of that header file is sufficient to provide access to the defined functionality, and the compiler will sort out the details?

Comment: `header.h` needs include guards ;)

Comment: Also I recommend compiling this by hand. `gcc main.c -c -o main.o`, `gcc source.c -c -o source.o`, `gcc main.o source.o -o program` will compile that. It makes it easy to see the separate compiled units and the linking at the end.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Converting C source code files to an executable program is normally done in two steps: **compiling** and **linking**.

First, the compiler converts the source code to object files (`*.o`). Then, the linker takes these object files, together with statically-linked libraries and creates an executable program.

In the first step, the compiler takes a **compilation unit**, which is normally a preprocessed source file (so, a source file with the contents of all the headers that it `#include`s) and converts that to an object file.

In each compilation unit, all the functions that are used must be **declared**, to let the compiler know that the function exists and what its arguments are. In your example, the declaration of the function `returnSeven` is in the header file `header.h`. When you compile `main.c`, you include the header with the declaration so that the compiler knows that `returnSeven` exists when it compiles `main.c`.

When the linker does its job, it needs to find the **definition** of each function. Each function has to be defined exactly once in one of the object files - if there are multiple object files that contain the definition of the same function, the linker will stop with an error.

Your function `returnSeven` is defined in `source.c` (and the `main` function is defined in `main.c`).

So, to summarize, you have two compilation units: `source.c` and `main.c` (with the header files that it includes). You compile these to two object files: `source.o` and `main.o`. The first one will contain the definition of `returnSeven`, the second one the definition of `main`. Then the linker will glue those two together in an executable program.

About linkage:

There is **external linkage** and **internal linkage**. By default, functions have external linkage, which means that the compiler makes these functions visible to the linker. If you make a function `static`, it has internal linkage - it is only visible inside the compilation unit in which it is defined (the linker won't know that it exists). This can be useful for functions that do something internally in a source file and that you want to hide from the rest of the program.

Answer (score 40):

The C language has no concept of source files and header files (and neither does the compiler).  This is merely a convention; remember that a header file is always `#include`d into a source file; the preprocessor literally just copy-pastes the contents, before proper compilation begins.

Your example *should* compile (foolish syntax errors notwithstanding).  Using GCC, for example, you might first do:

```
gcc -c -o source.o source.c
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
```

This compiles each source file separately, creating independent object files.  At this stage, `returnSeven()` has not been resolved inside `main.c`; the compiler has merely marked the object file in a way that states that it must be resolved in the future.  So at this stage, it's not a problem that `main.c` can't see a *definition* of `returnSeven()`.  (Note: this is distinct from the fact that `main.c` must be able to see a *declaration* of `returnSeven()` in order to compile; it must know that it is indeed a function, and what its prototype is.  That is why you must `#include "source.h"` in `main.c`.)

You then do:

```
gcc -o my_prog source.o main.o
```

This *links* the two object files together into an executable binary, and performs resolution of symbols.  In our example, this is possible, because `main.o` requires `returnSeven()`, and this is exposed by `source.o`.  In cases where everything doesn't match up, a linker error would result.

Comment: (Note: this is distinct from the fact that main.c must be able to see a declaration of returnSeven() : I am being pedantic, but this is not entirely correct. The compiler will happily compile (with a warning in C99) this code, and the linker resolve it, usually with bad effects. e.g. 
in file a.c, call `x=bob(1,2,3,4)` and in file b.c, `void bob(char *a){}` will compile, link  and run.

Comment: Absolutely world class answer. Love the minimalist GCC compiler instructions examples

Answer (score 15):

There is nothing magic about compilation. Nor automatic!

Header files basically provide information to the compiler, almost never code.
That information alone, is usually not enough to create a full program.

Consider the "hello world" program (with the simpler `puts` function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

without the header, the compiler does not know how to deal with `puts()` (it is not a C keyword). The header lets the compiler know how to manage the arguments and return value.

How the function works, however, is not specified anywhere in this simple code. Somebody else has written the code for `puts()` and included the compiled code in a library. The code in that library is included with the compiled code for your source as part of the compilation process.

Now consider you wanted your own version of `puts()`

```
int main(void) {
    myputs("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling just this code gives an error because the compiler has no information about the function. You can provide that information

```
int myputs(const char *line);
int main(void) {
    myputs("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

and the code now compiles --- but does not link, ie does not produce an executable, because there is no code for `myputs()`. So you write the code for `myputs()` in a file called "myputs.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int myputs(const char *line) {
    while (*line) putchar(*line++);
    return 0;
}
```

and you have to remember to compile **both** your first source file and "myputs.c" together.

After a while your "myputs.c" file has expanded to a hand full of functions and you need to include the information about all the functions (their prototypes) in the source files that want to use them.
It is more convenient to write all the prototypes in a single file and `#include` that file. With the inclusion you run no risk of making a mistake when typing the prototype.

You still have to compile and link all the code files together though.

---

When they grow even more, you put all the already compiled code in a library ... and that's another story :)

Answer (score 6):

Header files are used to separate the interface declarations which correspond to the implementations in the source files. They're abused in other ways, but this is the common case. This isn't for the compiler, it's for the humans writing the code.

Most compilers don't actually see the two files separately, they are combined by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler itself has no specific "knowledge" of relationships between source files and header files.  Those types of relationships are typically defined by project files (e.g., makefile, solution, etc.).

The given example appears as if it would compile correctly.  You would need to compile both source files and then the linker would need both object files to produce the executable.