# Undefined reference to an external class

Tags: c++, class

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\random\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x76)||undefined reference to `Tclass::FFunction()'|
```

I made my own class which is external from the main program and this is the error i get.
Here is the code of my program.

The main program(.cpp)

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Tclass.h"
#include "Tclass.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Tclass object;
    object.FFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

The header file. (.h)

```
#ifndef TCLASS_H
#define TCLASS_H


class Tclass
{
    public:
        Tclass();
        void FFunction();
};

#endif // TCLASS_H
```

The c++ style sheet(i think that's what it is called) (.cpp)

```
#include "Tclass.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

Tclass::Tclass()
{
    cout << "An object for this class has been created \n";
}

void FFunction(){
    cout << "The function has been created \n";
}
```

I am using code::block as my IDE. I also created the class with any destructors

Comment: Seems like you are missing the link for that object. Is TCone in a .a, .o, or in .h/.cpp format?

Comment: it is an .cpp format i believe. You are talking about the functions then it is in a .cpp format, if you are talking about the class, then its in a .h format.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  It looks like it is not linking `Cone.o` into the final executable.  Are all the `.cpp` source files included in your project?  It would seem that only `Main.cpp` is a build target.

Comment: If the library is in .h / .cpp format then just add their .cpp files into your compiler call... ex: g++ Cone.cpp Main.cpp

Comment: Im using a CODE::BLOCKER ide. I will be updating the code with a much shorter code so you can see the issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .cpp file:

```
void Tclass::FFunction(){
    cout << "The function has been created \n";
}
```

instead of:

```
void FFunction(){
    cout << "The function has been created \n";
}
```

also, there's no need to include `Tclass.cpp` in your main.

Comment: I tried it without the `Tclass.cpp` but it wouldn't run at all. But when i left the `Tclass.cpp` in the main it ran fine after i added the changes you gave me. Thanks ^^
The error i got when i removed the `Tclass.cpp`:
`C:\Users\PC\Desktop\random\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16)||undefined reference to Tclass::Tclass()'|``C:\Users\PC\Desktop\random\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x22)||undefined reference to `Tclass::FFunction()'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|`

Comment: @user2985134 that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Will this ever hinder the code? If so, ill try to re install the IDE.

Comment: will what hinder the code? not including `cpp` files? it most certainly shouldn't - it's the linker's job to find the function definitions. take a look at this (it's for C, but also applies to C++) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904530/understanding-header-and-source-files-in-c

Comment: So the IDE is at fault? I remember seeing someone else saying something about adding the `include"Tclass"` to make it run who is also using code::blocks. But then again i seen other who run it without it who are using the same IDE.
I also just went a little ballsy and it seems i didn't even need to include the header reference. I do not understand any more. It seems like the header isn't linking at all. Do you reckon this would be a good question to create another thread for?