# Using OpenACC with compiled C programs

Tags: openacc, samtools

I am trying to use OpenACC to accelerate the Samtools package by inserting pragmas at the applicable for loops.

```
linux86-64/19.4/bin/pgcc -acc autopar -ta=tesla config.h stats.c
```

I get the following error message:

```
stats.c:
PGC-F-0206-Can't find include file config.h (stats.c: 41)
PGC/x86-64 Linux 19.4-0: compilation aborted
```

I checked and the `config.h` file is in the same directory as the `stats.c` file. So I'm not sure how to resolve this error so that I can GPU accelerate samtools.

I've also tried to install samtools after adding the pragmas to the stats.c program but I am not seeing a difference in acceleration. I also check if GPU is being utilized during the run, for instance when I use samtools sort and no GPUs appear to be used.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting on your question. Please make a note of how I did this so you can do it yourself in the future.

Comment: You never compile `.h` files, they are only `#include`d. It seems like your problem is figuring out how to use C, not how to use OpenACC. I'd suggest trying to reformulate your question around that or searching on include/compile terms without worrying about OpenAcc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do header and source files in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904530/how-do-header-and-source-files-in-c-work)